# JQuery Descendant selector selects all elements on the Page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Code and Testcase at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iqazus/5/edit)

Basically, `$("#div-pmdialog span")` seems to select all SPANs on the page, whereas my understanding was that it should find only those SPANs which are descendants of `$("#div-pmdialog")`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML isn't parsed as you expect. The DOM inspector says it gets parsed as:

```
<div id="div-pmdialog">
    <p><span>hello</span></p><div id="div-pmdialog-text"><p></p>
  </div>

  <div id="div-indypcs-error"><span style="background-color:green">hello</span></div>    
</div>
```

HTML isn't XML. In HTML4 and older, self-closing tags was a no-op, mostly because browsers simply ignored the slash. I believe HTML5 specifies that some tags may be "self-closed", but only those that may *never* have any content, like `<img>` or `<br>`.

Answer (score 2):

Your jQuery are valid. Your html are not.

Here is, check it: http://jsbin.com/iqazus/6/edit

All `div` and `span` elements should have closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is being caused by your use of short tags on the `<span>` and `<div>` elements. It's working here: http://jsbin.com/iqazus/9/edit#preview

Answer (score -1):

hrmmmm try "span#div-pmdialog"